# Non-recursive Grey code algorithm understanding

Tags: algorithm, gray-code

This is task from algorithms book.

The thing is that I completely don't know where to start!

```
Trace the following non-recursive algorithm to generate the binary reflexive
Gray code of order 4. Start with the n-bit string of all 0’s. 
For i = 1, 2, ... 2^n-1, generate the i-th bit string by flipping bit b in the 
previous bit string, where b is the position of the least significant 1 in the 
binary representation of i.
```

So I know the Gray code for 1 bit should be `0 1`, for 2 `00 01 11 10` etc.

Many questions

1) Do I know that for n = 1 I can start of with `0 1`?

2) How should I understand "start with the n-bit string of all 0's"?

3) "Previous bit string"? Which string is the "previous"? Previous means from lower n-bit? (for instance for n=2, previous is the one from n=1)?

4) How do I even convert 1-bit strings to 2-bit strings if the only operation there is to flip?

This confuses me a lot. The only "human" method I understand so far is: take sets from lower n-bit, duplicate them, invert the 2nd set, add 0's to every element in 1st set, add 1's do every elements in 2nd set. Done (example: `0 1` -> `0 1 | 0 1` -> `0 1 | 1 0` -> `00 01 | 11 10` -> `11 01 11 10` done.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to all four your questions is that this algorithm does not start with lower values of `n`. All strings it generates have the same length, and the `i-th` (for `i` = 1, ..., 2<sup>n</sup>-1) string is generated from the `(i-1)-th` one.

Here is the fist few steps for n = 4:

Start with G<sub>0</sub> = `0000`

To generate G<sub>1</sub>, flip `0-th` bit in G<sub>0</sub>, as `0` is the position of the least significant `1` in the binary representation of 1 = 0001<sub>b</sub>. G<sub>1</sub> = `0001`.

To generate G<sub>2</sub>, flip `1-st` bit in G<sub>1</sub>, as `1` is the position of the least significant `1` in the binary representation of 2 = 0010<sub>b</sub>. G<sub>2</sub> = `0011`.

To generate G<sub>3</sub>, flip `0-th` bit in G<sub>2</sub>, as `0` is the position of the least significant `1` in the binary representation of 3 = 0011<sub>b</sub>. G<sub>3</sub> = `0010`.

To generate G<sub>4</sub>, flip `2-nd` bit in G<sub>3</sub>, as `2` is the position of the least significant `1` in the binary representation of 4 = 0100<sub>b</sub>. G<sub>4</sub> = `0110`.

To generate G<sub>5</sub>, flip `0-th` bit in G<sub>4</sub>, as `0` is the position of the least significant `1` in the binary representation of 5 = 0101<sub>b</sub>. G<sub>5</sub> = `0111`.

Comment: You could state the rule you use to increment as a generic rule for even/odd values :)